# Help with demonstration that the system $|p\rangle$ is complete

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

I have the following demonstration

$\langle x|x'\rangle = \langle x|(\int{|p\rangle \langle p|dp})|x'\rangle = \int{\langle x|p\rangle\overline{\langle x'|p\rangle}dx}=\int{e_{p}(x)\overline{e_{p}(x')}dx}=\delta(x-x')=\langle x|x'\rangle=\langle x|\cdot 1\cdot|x'\rangle$

I don't understand how in the second step we go from having an integral on dp to an integral on dx, if someone could explain I would appreciate it.

Comment: Although I know these things, also I do not understand that change. I do not even understand what they want to show. Or is it just a sequence of things that are equal, without any connection between the steps?

Comment: @md2perpe they want to show that the system $|p\rangle$ is complete, hence that $\int{|p\rangle \langle p|dp}=1$

Comment: How is the system $|p\rangle$ defined?

Comment: @md2perpe it's the impulsion

Comment: [Impulsion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulsion)? Don't you mean that $p$ stands for linear momentum? I know that, but how is the system $|p\rangle$ defined? Without a definition of the *system* nothing can be proved.

Comment: The dummy variable of integration is always *p*, so both of you *dx* s should have *stayed dp* s. This is the only way to produce the $\delta (x-x')$ following. You are trying to understand something that is not true.